# Javascript call java function with consuming operation on Android webview

Tags: java, javascript, android, webview

I develop android with phonegap.
There is a communication between javascript and java.

```
var img = server.getImage(); //javascript code
```

"Server" has defined as:

```
mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new DemoInterface(), "server"); //java code
```

"getImage" is a consuming operation.

```
public String getImage() {  
    Thread.sleep(2000); 
    return "";  
}
```

If I call server.getImage, my webview will freeze 2 second. 
One solution is to run consuming operation in a separate thread and callback javascript to set var img.

My question is if there are other solutions. For example javascript call java function in thread directly.

Any advice would be most welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue: I needed to call a consuming operation on Android.

I solved the issue, by designing my javascript call as an asynchronous call:

```
getImageMethod : function() {
    server.getImage("imageFoundMethod");
},

imageFoundMethod : function(image) {
    // image is the image variable returned by the javascript interface
}
```

I designed my JavascriptInterface in android this way:

```
private String callback;

public void getImage(String callback) {
    this.callback = callback;
    // Call a thread or an asynchronous object such as AsyncTask
    // The thread or the AsyncTask should call the method callbackJavascript
    // to send the answer back
}

public void callbackJavascript(String result) {
     mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:window." + this.callback + "(" + result + ");");
}
```

In this example result can also be a string representation of json object if you want to return some json back.

Here is a link to the AsyncTask documentation:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is a solution. But I want javascript can call java function and get return synchronous. Just like normal webpage get data from remote server.